# "Plays no games" vs. "doesn't play games" or "Says no words" vs. "Doesn't say words"

Tags: difference, word-difference, grammaticality-in-context

I wonder if there is a grammatical or stylistic difference between these contexts :

> He plays no games.

vs.

> He doesn't play games.

---

> He says no words.

vs.

> He doesn't say words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "VERB no" construction is much rarer and also is stronger, suggesting there is no exception.

> A: Does your Dad play chess?
>
> B: No, he doesn't play games.
>
> A: Well, does he at least play checkers?
>
> B: You don't understand. He plays no games!

Because the "VERB no" construction is stronger, it is used extremely rarely*. In the above conversation, B's final sentence is more likely,

> B: You don't understand. He doesn't play any games at all!

(Here, we can omit "any" or omit "at all" and get a sentence with the same meaning.)

*I can think of at least one exception: if the VERB is to have, the "VERB no" construction strikes me as being at least as common as the "DO NOT VERB" construction; not sure this is the only exception. Perhaps someone here can think of more.

Comment: I should add, your second example, "he says no words" sounds very strange, although everyone would understand you. We'd almost always say "he doesn't say any words."

Comment: Yes , I was about to write it "he doesn't say any words." but I wanted to make it similar to the first example.

Comment: Anyway , you say that "He does nothing" = He absolutely doesn't do anything" . That's is nearly what I need .

Comment: Yes, "He does nothing" = "He absolutely doesn't do anything." That's a very common sentence.

Comment: I would add that the second example also sounds a bit unusual because although it is not incorrect to say "says words," we would usually just say, "speak."